# Specify Dockerfile for gcloud build submit

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I understand `gcloud` uses the Dockerfile specified in the root directory of the source (`.`) as in the command:
`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/quickstart-image .`

but I am trying to specify the Dockerfile to use to build the image which I have not found any resource on how to do that, I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 21):

The only way to specify a Dockerfile (i.e. other than `./Dockerfile`) would be to create a `cloudbuild.yaml` per techtabu@. This config could then use the `docker` builder and provide the specific Dockerfile, i.e.:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args:
  - build
  - "--tag=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image"
  - "--file=./path/to/YourDockerFile"
  - .
...
images:
- "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image"
```

If you wish, you also get to specify an alternative name than `cloudbuild.yaml`.

The `./Dockerfile` assumption is presumably to ease the transition to Cloud Build.

I recommend you switch to using `cloudbuild.yaml` for the flexibility it provides.

Comment: How do I specify variables to the commands though? For example, adding a commit SHA (say SHA is available as $CI_COMMIT_SHA) to the image name in the tag?

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Comment: And: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg

Comment: Nice answer, thank you @DazWilkin. Anyway, @idrisadetunmbi, you can find the doc as link above or you can use for example`ENV NODE_ENV=development` in your Dockerfile to set environment variables.

Comment: I think it still needs the Dockerfile to be somewhere inside the directory you pass to the builder.

Answer (score 20):

You can very easily do this by substituting the `.` by `./path/to/YourDockerFile`, so the `gcloud` command will be:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/quickstart-image ./path/to/YourDockerFile
```

So you don't have to use a `cloudbuild.yaml` for this.

Comment: This didn't work for me: `ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) Local file [{src}] is none of .zip, .tgz, .gz`

Comment: @ZaarHai Just specify the *directory* containing the dockerfile, *not* the path to the file itself

Comment: That doesn't really help in my use case - I want to have one folder with two dockerfiles - one for dev (i.e. running unittests) and one for prod. Ended up using tar --transoform. See below.

Comment: this works for the case where you are OK with the build context of specified directory. However, for me it needed to be from repo root, so going with @DazWilkin answer above

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if you can specify Dockerfile, but you can use `cloudbuild.yaml` file. Check gcloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration). If you want to rename this file, you can use `config` option.

```sh
    gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

A sample `cloudbuild.yaml` file look like this,

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image', '.' ]
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the following hack works for me quite well. If you have e.g. `Dockerfile.prod` and `Dockerfile.dev` use the following to build the latter.

```
tar --exclude-vcs-ignores \  # sort-of .dockerignore support
    --transform='s|^\./Dockerfile.dev|./Dockerfile|' -zcf /tmp/togo.tgz . && \
            gcloud builds submit --tag=gcr.io/my-project/foo:latest /tmp/togo.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple solutions but they didn't work for me.
I was using the bitBucket pipeline So I used the following approach.

1. When I run **stage** env

   cp ./ENV/stage/Dockerfile ./Dockerfile
   gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/your-project/your-image
2. When I run **prod** env

   cp ./ENV/prod/Dockerfile ./Dockerfile
   gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/your-project/your-image

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34754577)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in my case was that the docker file has to be spelt with this case format Dockerfile.  I had DockerFile and it won't find that.  It is case sensitive.

Answer (score -2):

The `gcloud` build submit will detect automatically your `Dockerfile` if present, make sure your place the file in your `root directory`. If you don't know that much about docker you can use this command

```
gcloud beta run deploy --source=.
```

Execute it at your root directory. the `buildpacks` will create the `dockerfile`
for you and it is able to detect the stack of your application so it can build with its relevant tools.

Comment: the original question is useful if there are multiple Dockerfile files in the projects, as in the case of an NX monorepo, so having the dockerfile in the root is not an option, as we need a different Dockerfile for each project.