# Cloud Run, Deploy with Commands vs Deploy with InteliJ Cloud Code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am really suffering right now.. and I need to know why..
Somefiles (Excutable file like .exe) are not working if I do deploy with my commands. (And auto deploying with IntelliJ working perfectly after deploy)

and I really want to do same deploy like InteliJ does.

and here is the deploy code.  above one is I did myself

and below one is IntelliJ did

I really want to do same with IntelliJ Auto Deploy

See code please

---- DO IT MANUALLY WITH COMMANDS

In short, I used this

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<PROJECT-ID>

gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/<PROJECT-ID> --platform managed
```

In Long, Full Code

```
PS C:\go\abc-origin> gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin  
Creating temporary tarball archive of 82 file(s) totalling 9.3 MiB before compression.
Some files were not included in the source upload.                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                          
Check the gcloud log [C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2022.03.28\11.34.38.416229.log] to see which files and the contents of the
default gcloudignore file used (see `$ gcloud topic gcloudignore` to learn                                                                
more).                                                                                                                                    

Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/1648434878.494229-ae5063c025314197813db4b93ec85691.tgz]
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/abc-b13a0/locations/global/builds/313435fd-8c72-4230-9777-c9eb12b739fa].
Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/313435fd-8c72-4230-9777-c9eb12b739fa?project=291094557957].
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
starting build "313435fd-8c72-4230-9777-c9eb12b739fa"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/1648434878.494229-ae5063c025314197813db4b93ec85691.tgz#1648434880757751
Copying gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/1648434878.494229-ae5063c025314197813db4b93ec85691.tgz#1648434880757751...
/ [1 files][  8.6 MiB/  8.6 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/8.6 MiB.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  899.1kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:17-slim
17-slim: Pulling from library/node
ae13dd578326: Pulling fs layer
a0bc29d3bc64: Pulling fs layer
d0e0f1a959b4: Pulling fs layer
fe23f6dccded: Pulling fs layer
f23aa4f1504d: Pulling fs layer
fe23f6dccded: Waiting
f23aa4f1504d: Waiting
a0bc29d3bc64: Download complete
fe23f6dccded: Verifying Checksum
fe23f6dccded: Download complete
ae13dd578326: Verifying Checksum
ae13dd578326: Download complete
f23aa4f1504d: Verifying Checksum
f23aa4f1504d: Download complete
d0e0f1a959b4: Verifying Checksum
d0e0f1a959b4: Download complete
ae13dd578326: Pull complete
a0bc29d3bc64: Pull complete
d0e0f1a959b4: Pull complete
fe23f6dccded: Pull complete
f23aa4f1504d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:3894373926629c8e2c437314fb253b5d261efa6bddb2c947474406470fee2890
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:17-slim
 ---> 83d5dcf3f6f6
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in addca1bcb85e
Removing intermediate container addca1bcb85e
 ---> e0568396db62
Step 3/7 : COPY . .
 ---> ff239f669d09
Step 4/7 : COPY . ./
 ---> 78544462e12c
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 2e558015a5d5
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @types/mongoose@5.11.97: Mongoose publishes its own types, so you do not need to install this package.
npm WARN deprecated @types/helmet@4.0.0: This is a stub types definition. helmet provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated @types/iconv-lite@0.0.1: This is a stub types definition for iconv-lite (https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite). iconv-lite provides its own type definitions, so you don\'t need
 @types/iconv-lite installed!
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pinpoint@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/pinpoint'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/formula'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@4.1.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

added 1011 packages, and audited 1012 packages in 55s

77 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Removing intermediate container 2e558015a5d5
 ---> 5d7ff12b8075
Step 6/7 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in a2c0d89306c7

> nodejs-cloud-run-hello-world@0.0.1 build
> tsc --build
Removing intermediate container a2c0d89306c7
 ---> 96d13c4da119
Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm","start"]
 ---> Running in 3aaafeaa519c
Removing intermediate container 3aaafeaa519c
 ---> 0ffe22dfcae7
Successfully built 0ffe22dfcae7
Successfully tagged gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin:latest
PUSH
Pushing gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin]
1536374452a8: Preparing
6b04bb227785: Preparing
e86eb4a3c682: Preparing
5f8624a6a2ac: Preparing
05d059f19b02: Preparing
40ed0919f5f8: Preparing
016b2cae399b: Preparing
fd91c8bc8266: Preparing
009cb98a6eb1: Preparing
3a626bb08c24: Preparing
40ed0919f5f8: Waiting
016b2cae399b: Waiting
fd91c8bc8266: Waiting
009cb98a6eb1: Waiting
3a626bb08c24: Waiting
5f8624a6a2ac: Pushed
e86eb4a3c682: Pushed
05d059f19b02: Pushed
1536374452a8: Pushed
40ed0919f5f8: Layer already exists
009cb98a6eb1: Layer already exists
fd91c8bc8266: Layer already exists
016b2cae399b: Layer already exists
3a626bb08c24: Layer already exists
6b04bb227785: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:926c748640d78c396863bdf6fa8c246247bf0619e5a2764e87827f605349f6bc size: 2415
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID                                    CREATE_TIME                DURATION  SOURCE                                                                                      IMAGES
            STATUS
313435fd-8c72-4230-9777-c9eb12b739fa  2022-03-28T02:34:41+00:00  1M49S     gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/1648434878.494229-ae5063c025314197813db4b93ec85691.tgz  gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin
 (+1 more)  SUCCESS
PS C:\go\abc-origin> gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin --platform managed
```

---- INTELLIJ AUTO CLOUD RUN DEPLOYING DEFAULT

```
C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd run deploy abc-origin --quiet --image gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin --platform managed --project abc-b13a0 --memory 256Mi --timeout 300 --concurrency 80 --max-instances 1000 --cpu 1 --clear-env-vars --clear-cloudsql-instances --client-name "Cloud Code for IntelliJ" --client-version 22.2.1-213 --region asia-northeast1 --allow-unauthenticated --clear-vpc-connector

Preparing Google Cloud SDK (this may take several minutes for first time setup)...

Creating skaffold file: C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Temp\skaffold5770358230968925998.tmp...

Configuring image push settings in C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Temp\skaffold5770358230968925998.tmp...

C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\cloud-code\bin\versions\06e58efc4201989233a521d3211c1a2558e7db7b947e23aa203e5d2e46c990d3\skaffold.exe build --filename C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Temp\skaffold5770358230968925998.tmp --tag latest --skip-tests=true
Generating tags...
 - gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin -> gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin:latest
Checking cache...
 - gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin: Not found. Building
Starting build...
Building [gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin]...
Pushing code to gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/abc-b13a0-5556f485-72cc-4ccf-967d-bfdd1d0d5329.tar.gz
Logs are available at 
https://console.cloud.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/o/log-99f843b0-8ff0-4e4e-99d8-7abdc7bf30e4.txt
starting build "99f843b0-8ff0-4e4e-99d8-7abdc7bf30e4"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/abc-b13a0-5556f485-72cc-4ccf-967d-bfdd1d0d5329.tar.gz#1648433508081094
Copying gs://abc-b13a0_cloudbuild/source/abc-b13a0-5556f485-72cc-4ccf-967d-bfdd1d0d5329.tar.gz#1648433508081094...
/ [1 files][  9.2 MiB/  9.2 MiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/9.2 MiB.                                      
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.54MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:17-slim
17-slim: Pulling from library/node
ae13dd578326: Pulling fs layer
a0bc29d3bc64: Pulling fs layer
d0e0f1a959b4: Pulling fs layer
fe23f6dccded: Pulling fs layer
f23aa4f1504d: Pulling fs layer
fe23f6dccded: Waiting
f23aa4f1504d: Waiting
a0bc29d3bc64: Verifying Checksum
a0bc29d3bc64: Download complete
fe23f6dccded: Verifying Checksum
fe23f6dccded: Download complete
ae13dd578326: Verifying Checksum
ae13dd578326: Download complete
f23aa4f1504d: Verifying Checksum
f23aa4f1504d: Download complete
d0e0f1a959b4: Verifying Checksum
d0e0f1a959b4: Download complete
ae13dd578326: Pull complete
a0bc29d3bc64: Pull complete
d0e0f1a959b4: Pull complete
fe23f6dccded: Pull complete
f23aa4f1504d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:3894373926629c8e2c437314fb253b5d261efa6bddb2c947474406470fee2890
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:17-slim
 ---> 83d5dcf3f6f6
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 5c7029771a25
Removing intermediate container 5c7029771a25
 ---> 7b2ba07f192a
Step 3/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 8e1720a22a0a
Step 4/7 : COPY . ./
 ---> 3437788621d6
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 77bc58474b9a
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated @types/helmet@4.0.0: This is a stub types definition. helmet provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated @types/mongoose@5.11.97: Mongoose publishes its own types, so you do not need to install this package.
npm WARN deprecated @types/iconv-lite@0.0.1: This is a stub types definition for iconv-lite (https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite). iconv-lite provides its own type definitions, so you don\'t need @types/iconv-lite installed!
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/formula@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/formula'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/pinpoint@2.0.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/pinpoint'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@4.1.0: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@17.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

added 1011 packages, and audited 1012 packages in 58s

77 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing intermediate container 77bc58474b9a
 ---> 716aa89b15ed
Step 6/7 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 88daa40576c1

> nodejs-cloud-run-hello-world@0.0.1 build
> tsc --build

Removing intermediate container 88daa40576c1
 ---> f06d20cb4695
Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm","start"]
 ---> Running in 114dccd18b7b
Removing intermediate container 114dccd18b7b
 ---> 44eae9ff6f01
Successfully built 44eae9ff6f01
Successfully tagged gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin:latest
PUSH
Pushing gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin:latest
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin]
5ca13cc3b48f: Preparing
7e236c8bde4e: Preparing
da179f551c57: Preparing
bf4615d388ff: Preparing
c349e402c854: Preparing
40ed0919f5f8: Preparing
016b2cae399b: Preparing
fd91c8bc8266: Preparing
009cb98a6eb1: Preparing
3a626bb08c24: Preparing
40ed0919f5f8: Waiting
016b2cae399b: Waiting
fd91c8bc8266: Waiting
009cb98a6eb1: Waiting
3a626bb08c24: Waiting
c349e402c854: Pushed
40ed0919f5f8: Layer already exists
5ca13cc3b48f: Pushed
fd91c8bc8266: Layer already exists
016b2cae399b: Layer already exists
009cb98a6eb1: Layer already exists
3a626bb08c24: Layer already exists
bf4615d388ff: Pushed
da179f551c57: Pushed
7e236c8bde4e: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:efe017d86ad7a5f43a800b3acdb9519f1a0cf6aefc80d0291ba2f84fc32c08fa size: 2417
DONE

C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd run deploy abc-origin --quiet --image gcr.io/abc-b13a0/abc-origin --platform managed --project abc-b13a0 --memory 256Mi --timeout 300 --concurrency 80 --max-instances 1000 --cpu 1 --clear-env-vars --clear-cloudsql-instances --client-name "Cloud Code for IntelliJ" --client-version 22.2.1-213 --region asia-northeast1 --allow-unauthenticated --clear-vpc-connector
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [abc-origin] in project [abc-b13a0]
```

If IntelliJ does, it also declares a strange skaffold build statement. I want to follow IntelliJ for everything. How exactly should I run the command? I cannot rely on AUTO DEPLOY every time.

---

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM node:17-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build  
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: And what is the difference between tar.gz and .tgz ???? it is also different. how to make tar.gz by using pure commands??

Comment: You mentioned some files are not working if you deploy with your commands. In that case, are you getting any error? If so, could you share the error details?

Comment: @MousumiRoy No weird thing is except that, other things are working perfectly, it gets GET, POST normally.. and rendering page well also.. I suspect tar.gz and .tgz.. I think it should be tar.gz.. but do not know how to create with commands

Answer (score 0):

A .tar.gz file is *always* a simple archive of files, very much like a standard WinZip file. In the *general UNIX world*, a .tgz file is actually the same as a .tar.gz file. You can freely switch the extensions of these two without affecting the uncompression of the file. For more on this, you may refer to the [link](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-tgz-gz-files-2622391).

Now, coming to the deployment issue, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit),

```
To submit a build with local source source.tgz asynchronously:

gcloud builds submit "source.tgz" --tag=gcr.io/my-project/image --async
```

Also, have a look at this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327157/specify-dockerfile-for-gcloud-build-submit).

Comment: Yah I heard they`re almost same but not exactly same 0.01% different in someway.. anyway thanks, I want to create tar.gz not .tgz so giving commands are not for me I guess. tgz is automatically created by default when using normal commands

Comment: Seriously I really want to make tar.gz cloud build file, if u found, I immediately adopt this answer

Comment: And do u know skaffold build for cloud run manually too?

Comment: The standard command for cloud buils is:
gcloud builds submit [[SOURCE] --no-source] 
The location can be a directory on a local disk or a gzipped archive file (.tar.gz) in Google Cloud Storage.
Please refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit).
Also, I think you can use cloudbuild.yaml file. Have a look at this [document](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/gcp-cloud-run).

Comment: Yah I actually already saw that documentation but that example shows only for zip and .tgz and not tar.gz .. and about 2nd documentation.. I wont use Kubernetes. Kubernetes and Cloud runs is different they have same background but different

Answer (score -1):

I realized that the Cloud Code provided by GCP is a bit more futuristic than what can be solved with commands in the terminal. (more compatible in various ways) I've decided that intellij, vscode, or a shell editor is the best choice and there is no alternative for now.

--ADD

I just checked cloud shell editor cloud run deploy using cloud code. and it is not working too (can`t excute some program like I said in this question) I cloned from cloud source repository so, it is same code. (I checked)

What makes IntelliJ cloud code special exactly? I wonder

Why only this works..

---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).